# Agregar a favoritos

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy intentando generar un e-commerce de instrumentos donde los usuarios puedan una vez registrados añadir un producto a favoritos… honestamente no sé hacerlo y los tutoriales que halle no fueron productivos, podrían orientarme al menos como arrancarlo??? Muchas gracias

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './detalleProducto.module.css';

import { BsFillArrowLeftCircleFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import {GiMusicalScore, GiMusicSpell, GiMusicalNotes, GiMusicalKeyboard } from "react-icons/gi";

const DetalleProducto = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/data.json');
      const productsData = await response.json();
      const foundProduct = productsData.find((product) => product.id.toString() === id);


      setProduct(foundProduct);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  if (!product) {
    return <p>Producto no encontrado</p>;
  }

  return (

    <div className={styles.detalleProducto}>
      {/* Usar product en lugar de data */}
      <div key={product.id}>


        <section className={styles.detalleHeader}>
          <div className={styles.caracteristicas}> 
            <div className={styles.caracteristicasIndiv}> <b>< GiMusicalScore />Categoria:</b> <p>{product.categoria}</p> </div>
            <div className={styles.caracteristicasIndiv}> <b>< GiMusicSpell />Marca:</b> <p>{product.marca}</p> </div>
            <div className={styles.caracteristicasIndiv}> <b>< GiMusicalNotes />Modelo:</b> <p>{product.modelo}</p> </div>
            <div className={styles.caracteristicasIndiv}> <b>< GiMusicalKeyboard />Material:</b> <p>{product.material}</p> </div>
          </div>
          <Link to="/"><BsFillArrowLeftCircleFill color='#214F55' size={40}/></Link>
        </section>



        <section className={styles.detalleBody}>


          <article className={styles.ladoIzquierdo}>
            <h3 className={styles.h3}>{product.objeto}</h3>
            <p className={styles.productDescription}>{product.descripcion}</p>
            <div className={styles.precioBoton}>
              <p className={styles.precio}>$ {product.price}</p>
              <button className={styles.botonReserva}>Reservar</button>
            </div>
          </article>

          <article className={styles.ladoDerecho}>
            <div className={styles.imgContainer}>
              <div className={styles.productImageBox}>
                <img
                  src={product.img}
                  alt="img-product"
                  className={styles.productImage}
                />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.product4}>
                <div className={styles.product2}>
                  <img
                    src={product.img1}
                    alt="img-product"
                    className={styles.productImg}
                  />
                  <img
                    src={product.img2}
                    alt="img-product"
                    className={styles.productImg}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className={styles.product2}>
                  <img
                    src={product.img3}
                    alt="img-product"
                    className={styles.productImg}
                  />
                  <img
                    src={product.img4}
                    alt="img-product"
                    className={styles.productImg}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button className={styles.VerMasBox} >
              <Link className={styles.a} to={`/Galeria/${id}`}>
                Ver Más
              </Link>
            </button>
          </article>
        </section>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
  
};

export default DetalleProducto;
```

La idea sería colocarlo por donde está la flecha que nos admite a volver en el sector de atrás, honestamente no sé que más referencia colocar solo nos asignan ciertas user story con las cuales guiarnos para poder ejecutar la web (algo similar a Booking, pero a mi equipo le toco instrumentos musicales): como usuario autenticado quiero poder marcar productos como favoritos desde la lista de productos del home para poder acceder a ellos posteriormente.

Comment: Empieza agregando un boton con un evento `onClick`, y una funcion que recibe un ID para manejar la llamada del boton.

Answer (score 0):

No te compliques la vida. Tienes usuarios registrados, por lo tanto, sobre el mismo usuario, con un foreignKey lo vinculas a un arreglo de "favoritos", utilizando como ID la clase + su id, por ejemplo:

```javascript
// si son int
const arrByInt = ['guitar-123', 'synth-2382'];

// si son ids tipo string
const arrById = ['guitar-23aqwe-1223web', 'synth-2ggqwe-1223web'];
```

Luego, con esa información es muy sencillo validar cuáles pertenecen o no a los favoritos del cliente ya que en el arreglo de productos podrás obtener el tipo y ID que estás mapeando.

Sin embargo, lo que yo haría es concatenar objetos complejos que contengan el SLUG, thumbnail, descripción, etc. Lo que sea que necesites para pintar el UI según convenido. Esto lo resolvería a través de un microservicio y utilizaría estrategias de caché (REDIS) para evitar generar querys groseras que aumentarán tus tiempos de carga.

En realidad se trata simplemente de manejar un arreglo vinculado al usuario, nada más, lo podrías hacer hasta el LocalStorage sin problema, pero si quieres que quede en la nube, debes integrarlo a una DB, por lo tanto te debes enfocar el en microservicio que comunicará con el front para almacenar la info y su cliente. Si quieres algo brutal realtime, sockets, si no, REST y voilà.